# how to hang a handler on a collection of elements that returns to the querySelectorAll function?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to make a drop-down menu when clicking on itemDropDown, only the first one works, and the rest does not, querySelectorAll gives an error, what am I doing wrong? I have attached jsfidle so you can help, don'ts please pay attention to scss. http://jsfiddle.net/rhy7pv1f/46/

```
const itemDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__list-item.drop__down'),
            itemList = document.querySelector('.drop__down-list');


itemDropDown.forEach((buttonItem) => {
  buttonItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    itemList.classList.toggle('active');
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your handlers toggle the class of the one `itemList` you create at the start.

You need to target the relevant list for each button.

```js
const itemDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__list-item.drop__down');


itemDropDown.forEach((buttonItem) => {
  const relatedDropdownList = buttonItem.querySelector('.drop__down-list');
  const dropDownLink = buttonItem.querySelector('.menu__list-link');

  dropDownLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    relatedDropdownList.classList.toggle('active');
  });

})
```

Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/k7b0m95a/5/